ERROR No metadata for <entity> was found
Buenos dias tardes o noches. Estoy practicando nestJS y tengo un problema ya que intento leer una BD la cual tiene tablas y quiero acceder a una de ellas. Pero me sale el isguiente error: ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No metada for < entity > was found
En teoria tengo todo en orden hasta donde e leido y me e documentado no se que estoy haciendo mal:
main.ts:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.setGlobalPrefix("api/v1");

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
    })
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

app.module:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Tacce2Module } from './tacce2/tacce2.module';
import { TchiaModule } from './tchia/tchia.module';   

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports:[ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_NAME')
      }),
      inject:[ConfigService],
    }),
    TchiaModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }

tchia.entyti.ts:
import { Column, Entity } from "typeorm";

@Entity('tchia')
export class Tchia {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    CODIGOCAJA:string

    @Column()
    NOMBCAJA:string

    @Column()
    CODICONT:string
}

tchia.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Tchia } from './entities/tchia.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TchiaService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Tchia)
    private readonly tchiaRepository: Repository<Tchia>
  ) {}

  findAll() {
    return this.tchiaRepository.find()
  }

  findOne(id: number) {
    return `This action returns a #${id} tchia`;
  }
}


tchia.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Patch, Param, Delete } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TchiaService } from './tchia.service';

@Controller('tchia')
export class TchiaController {

  constructor(private readonly tchiaService: TchiaService) {}
  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.tchiaService.findAll();
  }

  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.tchiaService.findOne(+id);
  }
}


Basicamente es todo el proyecto. Solo quiero agarrar los datos de la BD y poder leer esa tabla. lo e intentado ya, con las demas tablas y siempre me da el mismo error. A lo mejor es una configuracion que no veo o algo que desconozco. pero llevo varios dias intentado solucionar el problema y aun no encuentro la forma de solucionarlo. Les agradeceria mucho el saber si me pueden ayudar porfavor

Ya actualice la respuesta.

Te falta el decorador @ en tu entidad, tiene que ser
import { Column, Entity } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('tchia')
export class Tchia {}

Actualización:
TypeORM no permite crear entidades sin llave primaria, agrega un campo:
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

Agrego, como consejo, tal vez quieras renombrar la entidad a Caja y tener id, 'nombre', etc; en lugar de repetir "Caja" cada en cada campo. Es más legible, sigue el principio D.R.Y (Don't repeat yourself - no te repitas) y facilita las consultas: caja.id, caja.nombre en lugar de tchia.CODIGOCAJA y tchia.NOMBCAJA
Actualización 2
Agrega autoLoadEntities: true en TypeOrmModule.forRoot() para cargar las entidades de forma automatica.
Fuente:
Entities | typeorm

Hola buenas tardes. Y es la segunda opcion con la que estoy trabajando, y claro esa import lo tengo ya agregado desde el inicio

Ya vi tu error, deja edito la pregunta.

Tenias razon. Me faltaba el @ en Entity. Pero, aun sigue con el mismo error. Voy a editar la pregunta de arriba habiendo corregido eso

Agrega los otros dos módulos.

Hermano agregue el controller que era el que faltaba. Por que no estoy trabajando con otros modulos. Solo con ese que es el tchia

Si, eso también fue lo que hice. Puse a CODIGOCAJA con primarykey por que estaba haciendo unas pruebas. Dichas pruebas funcionaron (creo). Pero aun tengo el mismo problema de que no me deja visualizar el contenido de la tabla. Ya que me marca ese error. Voy actualizar la pregunta

En tu TypeORMModule.forRoot agrega autoLoadEntities: true o si no haz referencia a las entities Entities: [Tchia].

Listo hermano. Muchas gracias faltaba el autoLoadEntities: true, no se como agradecerte llevaba todo el dia en esto. Muchisimas gracias hermano
